# Установить размер пункта меню li по размеру ширины выпадающего

Tags: css, wordpress

Есть меню на WordPress. Есть горизонтальное меню с выпадающими пунктами. Нужно, что бы пункты основного меню растягивались  в соответствии с шириной выпадающего. Ширина выпадающего, в свою очередь, зависит от длины строки названия пункта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на картинке - пункт выпадающий шире, чем выделенный родительский пункт.

Т.к. это меню WordPress, лезть в файлы шаблона не хотелось бы совсем, а вот свои стили для ul, li и т.д. задать было бы самое то. Так же крайне не хотелось бы использовать JS и прочие скрипты.

Comment: С помощью css вы не можете воздействовать на свойства родительского элемента в зависимости от дочернего. Никак, от слова совсем. Без js не обойтись.

Comment: Это очень и очень печально. Так как сейчас есть - не очень смотрится...что делать, ума не приложу(

Comment: Что делать - несколько строк на js и все

Comment: А каких?) Не силен я в js, и даже в том, куда их в данном случае вписать

Comment: Вы разметку своего меню покажите. Без html кода вам не помогут.

Answer (score 0):

Если это бутстрап, то попробуйте дать классу dropdown-menu - width: 100%;
Однако, возможно, что длинный текст будет "выпадать" за блок.

Comment: Это я пробовал, получается что выпадающее меню подравнивается под ширину родительского. и текст переносится на вторую строку. Вообщем получается что выравнивается не родительский по ширине выпадающего а наоборот.